# What tools are recommended for sending mass dynamic emails?

Tags: email

I feel like this question ought to have been covered, but I can't seem to find specifically what I'm after in here.

Is it a good idea to use my own server for mass emailing my mailing lists, or are there good, trusted tools that achieve this and that can be easily integrated with different datasets?

Should I opt for a pay service?

When making websites, email seems such a gray area to me, I'm never sure what the best way to do it is.

**If there is a tool**

I'd like a bit of software that I can integrate with some database (SQL, or Excel, or CSV.. I don't mind) that will allow me to make dynamic HTML and send them to 100s/1000s of people.

I don't mind if it's software or if it's webware as long as it can do the job reliably.

It can be a pay service, because I understand that if I get my one server's IP black listed then I'm in trouble - best off using a dedicated email company to get this done (or have I got this wrong?).

It would be good if there was some kind of API that can be used, or web service, to send individual emails dynamically from a language (ideally .NET).

I need it for two purposes:

- Sending out newsletters (doesn't need code integration)
- Sending out account confirm emails etc. (does need code integration)

I know I can easily send the individual emails from my server using .NET, but it seems a good idea to keep all email sending in one place.

Does anyone have any recommendations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the biggest provider of email services in the world is [Epsilon](http://www.epsilon.com/Email-and-Digital-brSolutions/p34-l1), formerly DreamMail.

If you are worrying about having more control then you could buy a [StrongMail](http://www.strongmail.com/) appliance and include the white/black listing service to help with the constant delivery battle.

Answer (score 1):

I use [MailChimp](http://mailchimp.com/) and I'm very happy. They have [extensive APIs](http://www.mailchimp.com/api/) with great support people that can help with the integration. They have tools which fit your exact needs. The reports are excellent and they keep improving.

Comment: Ooh they have nice graphics on their website - sold! :)

Comment: Yes, they cracked the "cool" factor all right...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not sending the emails, it is getting around spam filters. It is typically worth the money to use a service because the service will do all of the legwork of ensuring they are white-listed with the major carriers.

Comment: Well yes, that's why I pointed out that I didn't want to get black listed. Being marked as spam is a big concern. Any recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

For newsletters, NewsWeaver is pretty good.
You can find it here:
[http://www.newsweaver.co.uk/](http://www.newsweaver.co.uk)

As for integration with code we ended up writing our own and using our own SMTP server to send them out.

Answer (score 0):

We have had great success with http://www.briefyourmarket.com/

They have a web service api, and the templates are scriptable.

Answer (score 0):

ActiveTrail ([www.activetrail.com](http://www.activetrail.com)) can do mass email with simple web-service api and excellent deliverability.

(proper disclosure: I *am* somewhat affiliated with them)